# Control sizing has last item sizing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The control is to show a design with its name and price in the top left and bottom right. I'm re-coding a program from windows forms and I created a custom control there. I'm just trying to reproduce it in WPF and its a struggle bus
the control works atm but it doesn't work with the first image for sizing
or if the image I pull up is a different size from the prior image.

The issue is that the code doesn't get the correct sizing until after the load event.

"so I recon the main question is how to get the sizing then trigger the second event to update the overlay."

image of the control outcome:

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvmJt.jpg

issue image second load diffrent aspect ratio:

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKq9N.jpg

The second image loaded again fixes sizing issue:

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYfJI.jpg

Also, I've been reading up on trying to turn this control into a reusable control any advise/suggestion of where to start in understanding that system in WPF would be greatly appreciated

the following code is what I got to work to get the base layout I want. I still need to theme it better but the overall layout is mostly correct. 
I tried playing with canvas but couldn't get the right layout

for all I know this could be completely wrong so if theirs a better way please state so. I don't want to fumble down the wrong path.

Xaml
the fix was Sizechanged event for updating after source loaded.

```xml
 <Image x:Name="pbMainImage"  Source="{Binding Path=(local:SV.PbMainImage), Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter},
                        Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center" SizeChanged="name_price_sizingbclick"/>
```

```xml
<Button Name="pbbutton" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  Click="pbmain_Click" SizeChanged="name_price_sizingbclick">

    <Border Name="Test" Grid.Row="0"   Margin="{Binding Path=(local:SV.pading)}" Background="#252525">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=(local:SV.Imagespacing)}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=(local:SV.Imagespacing)}"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height=".15*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height=".15*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="border" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="3" ClipToBounds="True" >
                <Image x:Name="pbMainImage"  Source="{Binding Path=(local:SV.PbMainImage), Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter},
Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center"/>
            </local:ZoomBorder>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Background="Orange" Opacity=".8"  FontWeight="Bold" Padding="10 0 10 0" TextAlignment="Center" >
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:SV.ActiveDesign)}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Viewbox>
</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="3" Background="GreenYellow" Opacity=".8" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="10 0 10 0" TextAlignment="Center"  >
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=(local:SV.sprice),StringFormat=${0}}" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Viewbox>
</TextBlock>

            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Panel.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Content="4" Click="prevImg" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Panel.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Content="4" Click="nextvImg" Visibility="Hidden" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Button>
```

C#

```cs
//this is what moves the overlays around. on source change it runs when source is changed
public static void name_price_sizing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow myWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
    Button p = myWindow.pbbutton;
    Image i = myWindow.pbMainImage;
    if (toggle == 0)
    {
        SV.Imagespacing = Math.Round(((p.ActualWidth - i.ActualWidth) / 2) / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2 - 14;
    }
    else { SV.Imagespacing = Math.Round(((p.ActualWidth - i.ActualWidth) / 2) / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2; }
    if (SV.Imagespacing < 0) { SV.Imagespacing = 0; }
}
//this is what moves the overlays around. on control click to resize for fullscreen
public void name_price_sizingbClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //  StaticVariables.Imagespacing = (pbbutton.ActualWidth - pbMainImage.ActualWidth) / 2;
    if (toggle == 0) { SV.Imagespacing = Math.Round(((pbbutton.ActualWidth - pbMainImage.ActualWidth) / 2) / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2 - 14; } else { SV.Imagespacing = Math.Round(((pbbutton.ActualWidth - pbMainImage.ActualWidth) / 2) / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 2; }
    if (SV.Imagespacing < 0) { SV.Imagespacing = 0; }

}
```

Comment: i have solved my issue not sure how to mark this as solved.
i added  SizeChanged="name_price_sizingbclick" to image control and it fixed the sizing issue. i would still like a look over on the code for tips and any assistance on how to make this control into a re usable user control.

Comment: To mark it as solved you should have added an answer and not edit the questin thats kinda confusing for people comming around now when they have not seen the original question. It would be great if you could attach a screenshot of the orognal winfirms control so we can see what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

> I have solved my issue not sure how to mark this as solved.
>   I added `SizeChanged="name_price_sizingbclick"` to image control and it fixed the sizing issue. I would still like a look over on the code for tips and any assistance on how to make this control into a reusable user control.

Cut out of the question as the op answered it himself and did not write it as an answer.